# Finite generation of cones in $\mathbf{Z}^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, monoid, finitely-generated

Let $X$ be a finite free $\mathbf{Z}$-module of rank $n$ and let $X_+ \subset X$ be a cone i.e. a subset of $X$ such that for any $x,y \in X_+$ and  $a,b \in \mathbf{N}$ we have $ax+by \in X_+$.

Is it true that that $X_+$ is finitely generated in the sense that there exist elements $x_1,\dots,x_d \in X_+$ such that any element in $X_+$ is a $\mathbf{N}$-linear combination of $x_1,\dots,x_d$ ?

If this is not true does it help if I assume that there are elements $e_1,\dots,e_n \in X_+$ which form a basis of $X \otimes_{\mathbf{Z}} \mathbf{Q}$. Of course $e_1,\dots,e_n$ need not be generators of $X_+$.

Is this is not true are there some conditions that ensure that the result is true ?

Comment: Nope. For a counterexample, take the cone consisting of all $\left(u,v\right) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$ such that $u \geq 0$ and $v \geq 0$ and $u^2 \geq 2v^2$. Each continued-fraction approximation of $\sqrt{2}$ will produce a point in the cone that cannot be written as a nontrivial $\mathbb{N}$-linear combination of smaller points.

Comment: It's even false if you assume that the positive real cone generated by $X$ is a rational polyhedral cone: take $X=\{(0,0\}\}\cup\mathbf{N}_{>0}^2$.

Comment: @YCor: Right, your example follows from my more general criterion, because the slope function in your example has no minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not true in general that $X_+$ is finitely generated. A simple counterexample is to choose an irrational number $s > 0$ and take $X_+ = \{(a,b) \in \mathbb N^2 \mid 0 < \frac{b}{a} < s\}$. More generally, if $X_+$ is contained in the first quadrant (say), if $r,R \in [0,\infty]$ are the infimum and supremum of the slopes $\frac{b}{a}$ for $(a,b) \in X_+$, and if $X_+$ is finitely generated, then $r$ is the minimum slope of a generator and $R$ is the maximum slope of a generator.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Do you know if there are criteria for finite generation ?